# How to make select-string only match records that are 6 characters long?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0, select-string

I’m creating a script that reads a text file and compares the results to an array. It works fine, but I have some records that say they match but they don’t.

For example - `TG1032` and `TG` match according to the `select-string` script.

Here is my `select-string`:

```
$Sel = select-string -pattern $strArrVal -path $txt
```

Is there a way to alter this to make select-string only match records that are 6 characters long?

Comment: You _need_ to show us some sample text with things that are supposed to match and not as well as your pattern string. Does `^.{6}$` work?

Comment: `Get-Content $txt | Where-Object{$_.length -eq 6}` is also a solution since this does not really need to be regex for match just any 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to point out where your pattern is wrong but the solution will most likely be the same regardless. If you are looking to match lines that are exactly 6 characters then you could just use the pattern `^.{6}$`.

```
$strArrVal = "^.{6}$"
Select-String -Pattern $strArrVal -Path $txt
```

If that is really all you are looking for then regex is not really required. You could do this with `Get-Content` with similar results

```
Get-Content $txt | Where-Object{$_.length -eq 6}
```